# Pushing only certain changes to all branches in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I have a mercurial repository with numerous branches for stable, development, experimental features etc. However, I've found a bug in a set of core application files that are common to each branch.

Is there a way to modify these files, and then push the changes to the common files to all the other branches, without sending any other changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideal way is to make the changes on the most stable branch, and then merge the change into the other branches. If you can, you should aim to have a hierarchy of branches so that stable is a subset of development, which is a subset of experimental.

That means that you will always pull from stable into development, and from development into experimental. This way you wont forget to propagate a bugfix, you just always pull and merge.

However, people do forget to put the bugfixes on the right branch from time to time. It also happens that a bugfix is upgraded in severity after it was put on development, say, and now you need it on stable as well.

The [transplant extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TransplantExtension) is there to help you with that. You use it to copy a change from one place to another. Please see [my recent tutorial on tast based development](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/tasks.html#transplanting-changes) for nice screenshots and a walk-through.